# Why when using TPC inheritance is Select query using left outer join?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

In a database I have `Reservations` and `OldReservations` tables, where OldReservations is a copy ( of `Reservations` table ) and is used to store old reservations. Here are the steps I did to create TPC inheritance:

1) I derived `OldReservation` entity from `Reservations` entity 
2) I removed the overlapping properties from `OldReservations` entity 
3) I've then mapped the `OldReservations` table fields in the XML of the EDMX file

But when I run the folllowing query, the generated sql uses LEFT OUTER JOIN, which doesn't make sense, since it means that query will only return rows from `OldReservations` table where `Reservations.ReservationID == OldReservations.ReservationID`. From the articles I've read it seems that the above query should use an UNION operator and not the LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
        var reservations = context.Reservations;
        foreach (var item in reservations);
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN (NOT (([Project1].[C1] = 1)
                    AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) THEN '0X'
         ELSE '0X0X'
       END                         AS [C1],
       [Extent1].[ReservationID]   AS [ReservationID],
       [Extent1].[ReservationDate] AS [ReservationDate],
       [Extent1].[ContactID]       AS [ContactID],
       [Extent1].[EventID]         AS [EventID],
       [Extent1].[RowVersion]      AS [RowVersion]
FROM   [dbo].[Reservations] AS [Extent1]
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [Extent2].[ReservationID] AS [ReservationID],
                               cast(1 as bit)            AS [C1]
                        FROM   [dbo].[OldReservations] AS [Extent2]) AS [Project1]
         ON [Extent1].[ReservationID] = [Project1].[ReservationID]
```

TPC select query using left outer join doesn't make sense, so what am I doing wrong when creating TPC inheritance?

thank you

Comment: This looks like query for TPT inheritance.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed your reply. I'm not sure what you're getting at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how TPC is supposed to work. `Reservation` is a concrete type, so the properties in `Reservation` are stored in the `Reservations` table. `OldReservation` is also a concrete type, so the properties in `OldReservation` **that aren't already mapped** are stored in the `OldReservations` table.

What you want is similar, but not quite the same. Make `Reservation` an abstract type and rename it to `ReservationBase`. Then create a derived type `Reservation`. Now `OldReservation` no longer derives from a concrete type, so all of `OldReservation` own properties and inherited properties will map to the OldReservations table.

After that, `yourContext.ReservationBases` can be used to get both `Reservations` and `OldReservations`, and that should use a `UNION (ALL)`.

Comment: I've renamed Reservation into ReservationBase --> changed it into an abstract type --> created derived type Reservation --> and mapped this derived type to Reservations table. But now I get error "EntityTypes BAModel.OldReservation, BAModel.Reservation are being mapped to the same rows in table Reservations. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to". From the error it appears that EF is trying to map OldReservation entity to Reservations table instead of OldReservations table?! Is the only option to use a mapping condition or is there a workaround?

Comment: @user702769 Does your `OldReservation` still derive from `Reservation`? If so, it shouldn't, it should derive from `ReservationBase`.

Comment: @user702769 Another possibility, make sure `ReservationBase` isn't mapped to any table. Only `Reservation` and `OldReservation` should be.

Comment: "make sure ReservationBase isn't mapped to any table. Only Reservation and OldReservation should be" But if ReservationBase doesn't map columns common to both Reservation and OldReservation tables, then what exactly is the point of using TPC inheritance? BTW - OldReservation derives from ReservationBase

Comment: @user702769 I think I'm not fully understanding you. Do you want `Reservation` and `OldReservation`'s common properties to be mapped to be different tables, or not? If you don't, then in order to get the right results at the database level, you need the left join, so what you had was right. If you do, then you cannot map `ReservationBase` to a single table, because the table will depend on whether the `ReservationBase` is a `Reservation` or an `OldReservation`.

Comment: I think I'm completely off with my understanding of TPC. I thought the whole point of using TPC was to have base type that would map overlapping properties ( thus properties common to all of derived types). But if ReservationBase is not mapped to either Reservations or OldReservations, then do we still have TPC inheritance? I'm totally lost now

Comment: @user702769 Depending on whether the base type of OldReservations (Reservations in your case, ReservationsBase in mine) is a concrete (non-abstract) type, the properties in that base type may be mapped to a single table (your example) or to different tables (my example). They're both TPC. TPC only specifies how your model is mapped to the database, not how your model is organised.

Comment: In case you're willing to help me a bit more: 1) is the whole point of using TPC that if otherwise unrelated tables have overlapping fields, then we can define those common properties in abstract base class, from which entities ( mapped to tables with overlapping fields ) derive? 2) If my assumptions are correct, why then do I get an error if overlapping properties are defined in ReservationBase ( which is abstract and is not mapped to any table --> Reservation and OldReservation derive from it and are mapped to their tables)?

Comment: @user702769 See http://pastebin.com/T05mndq2 for an example, `Entity1` is an abstract base class from which both `Entity2` and `Entity3` are derived. The base class property `Field1` is stored in the `Entity2Set` and `Entity3Set` tables.

Comment: Ah, it's working now. I checked your example and as it turned out, I already did have correct mappings, but for some reason ReservationBase had "_1" appended to each of its properties, which I didn't notice before. Yay, I can't thank you enough.

Comment: If I may just ask to be sure, am I correct in assuming that the whole point of using TPC is that if otherwise unrelated tables have overlapping fields, then we can define those common properties in abstract base class, from which entities ( mapped to tables with overlapping fields ) derive? BTW - I will mark this thread as answered in few hours, regardless of whether you answer my question or not

Comment: @user702769 That's not the whole point. TPC is more generally useful if you have methods that work on either a `Reservation` or an `OldReservation`, or if you want to extend the entities with unmapped properties. On the other hand, TPC is usable but not useful if you have identical fields in different tables that are logically unrelated.

Comment: "TPC is more generally useful if you have methods that work on either a Reservation or an OldReservation" And these methods should be defined in a base entity ( ie ReservationBase )?

Comment: @user702769 They could be, or they could be separate methods that take a `ReservationBase` parameter. As a simplified example, something I'm using TPC for is an abstract base class that has `LastModified` and `LastModifiedBy` properties, and a method to update these two properties depending on the user that is currently logged in.